# Plug into the hierarchy of Spring Boot property sources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I know the default order of spring's properties sources: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
how can i add my own property source with a specific precedence?

`@PropertySource` is not enough as it adds new properties with very low priority

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways to do this; [I'll just quote the official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context):

> A `SpringApplication` has `ApplicationListener`s and `ApplicationContextInitializer`s that are used to apply customizations to the context or environment. Spring Boot loads a number of such customizations for use internally from `META-INF/spring.factories`. There is more than one way to register additional ones:
>
> - Programmatically per application by calling the `addListeners` and `addInitializers` methods on `SpringApplication` before you run it.
> - Declaratively per application by setting `context.initializer.classes` or `context.listener.classes`.
> - Declaratively for all applications by adding a `META-INF/spring.factories` and packaging a jar file that the applications all use as a library.
>
> The `SpringApplication` sends some special `ApplicationEvents` to the listeners (even some before the context is created), and then registers the listeners for events published by the ApplicationContext as well. See [Section 23.4, “Application events and listeners”](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) in the ‘Spring Boot features’ section for a complete list.
>
> It is also possible to customize the `Environment` before the application context is refreshed using `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. Each implementation should be registered in `META-INF/spring.factories`:
>
> ```
> org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.example.YourEnvironmentPostProcessor
> ```

My way was always to add an ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent listener:

```
public class IntegrationTestBootstrapApplicationListener implements
    ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent>, Ordered {

    public static final int DEFAULT_ORDER = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 4;
    public static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "integrationTestProps";

    private int order = DEFAULT_ORDER;

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();

        if (!environment.getPropertySources().contains(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME)) {
            Map<String, Object> properties = ...; // generate the values

            // use whatever precedence you want - first, last, before, after
            environment.getPropertySources().addLast(
              new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, properties));
        }
    }

}
```

But you can just as easily use an initializer:

```
public class IntegrationTestBootstrapApplicationListener implements
    ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "integrationTestProps";

    @Override
    public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        Map<String, Object> properties = ...; // generate the values

        // use whatever precedence you want - first, last, before, after
        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(
            new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, properties));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you describe make spring to detect your initializer? Where is this class used?

Comment: There's already a description in the quoted text, see the bullet list for details.

Comment: Adding to META-INF/spring.factories didn't work for me

Comment: It's unlikely that the feature doesn't work since the whole of Spring Boot's auto-configuration relies on spring.factories, you probably made a mistake somewhere :)